# Using CSS to change Select List Option background color of each option value

Tags: css

I want to change Select List Option background color of each option value but its not working.

I cannot give a class on each items because its auto generated from a core script.

Is there any way to use using CSS3 without using Javascript?

```css
select option {
    margin:5px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
select option[val="blue-1"]{
    background: rgb(18,85,164);
    background-color:#1255a4 !important;
}
select option[val="black-2"]{
    background: rgb(37,40,42);
}

select option[val="pink-3"]{
    background: rgb(230,104,158);
}

select option[val="purple-4"]{
    background: rgb(100,40,255);
}
select option[val="yellow-5"]{
    background: rgb(245,210,40);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `value="..."`, not `val="..."`. `val` isn't a HTML property, whereas `value` is.

[image: Example Image]

```css
select option {
  margin:5px;
  color:#ffffff;
   text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
select option[value="blue-1"] {
  background: #1255a4;
}

select option[value="black-2"] {
  background: rgb(37,40,42);
}

select option[value="pink-3"] {
    background: rgb(230,104,158);
}

select option[value="purple-4"] {
    background: rgb(100,40,255);
}
select option[value="yellow-5"] {
    background: rgb(245,210,40);
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="blue-1">Blue</option>
  <option value="black-2">Black</option>
  <option value="pink-3">Pink</option>
  <option value="purple-4">Purple</option>
  <option value="yellow-5">Yellow</option>
</select>
```