# Adding an :after element on "select" options

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to add colored bordered boxes at the right of each option of a "select".

My html code is:

```
<select id="" name="" size="0" class="">
<option value="label_0" class=" level-label"></option>
<option value="241" class="has-no-children" selected="selected">White</option>
<option value="242" class="has-no-children">Black</option>
<option value="243" class="has-no-children">Red</option>
</select>
```

and my CSS:

```
select option {
   position: relative;
}

select option:after {
   content: "";
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   border: 1px solid #222;
   background-color: white;
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
}

select option:nth-child(2):after {
   background-color: black;
}

select option:nth-child(3):after {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Unfortunately, no `:after` element appears on html.

Note that I don't have the opportunity to edit the select html (by php probably), so I have to make it by CSS or jQuery only.

Comment: @BrainFooLong i suppose every question is a dupe of itself ("Kappa")

Comment: Holy moly, sorry. This -> :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198195/how-can-i-use-the-css-pseudo-element-before-content-to-affect-an-option

Comment: You will need to create a custom select with divs and such and you will need to edit the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short anwser**

You can't add `:pseudo` elements to `inputs` and `image` elements.

**Alternative?**

Well, you could use `jquery`. But this still won't work on the `option` element.

```
$("select").after("Hello");
```

**Snippet**

```js
$("select").after("Hello");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="" name="" size="0" class="">
<option value="label_0" class=" level-label"></option>
<option value="241" class="has-no-children" selected="selected">White</option>
<option value="242" class="has-no-children">Black</option>
<option value="243" class="has-no-children">Red</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Unfortunately you are right, this can't be done like this, I'll try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278614/using-css-to-change-select-list-option-background-color-of-each-option-value instead