# How do I add an ::after element on a <select>?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to have an ::after element on my select element.

This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48992364/10551293) says that I cannot have ::after or ::before on input elements, does the select tag count as an input element? (It's not an  though)

The following doesn't work:

```
select::after {
    content: "hello";
}
```

How would I do this (without jQuery, preferably without javascript as well)?

Comment: Have a look at this post. Might be this is useful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25574218/8732191

Answer (score 0):

```css
.caja {
   margin:20px auto 40px auto; 
   border:1px solid #d9d9d9;
   height:30px;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 230px;
   position:relative;
}
select {
   background: transparent;
   border: none;
   font-size: 14px;
   height: 30px;
   padding: 5px;
   width: 250px;
}
select:focus{ outline: none;}

.caja::after{
 content:"\025be";
 display:table-cell;
 padding-top:7px;
 text-align:center;
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 background-color:#d9d9d9;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0px; 
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja">
  <select>
    <option>La primera opción</option>
    <option>La segunda opción</option>
    <option>La tercera opción</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

[problem with <select> and :after with CSS in WebKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532649/problem-with-select-and-after-with-css-in-webkit)